# MPI matrix multiplication, process not cleaning up

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, mpi

Im trying to use MPI to multiply two nxn matrices. The second matrix (bb) is broadcasted to all "slaves" and then it is sent a row from the first matrix (aa) to compute the product. It then sends back the answer to the master process and is stored in the product matrix cc. For some reason I'm getting the error:

```
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

I believe that the master process is recieving all the messages sent by slave process and vice-versa so I'm not sure what is going on here... any ideas?

Main:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#define min(x, y) ((x)<(y)?(x):(y))
#define MASTER 0

double* gen_matrix(int n, int m);
int mmult(double *c, double *a, int aRows, int aCols, double *b, int bRows, int bCols);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int nrows, ncols;
    double *aa;     /* the A matrix */
    double *bb;     /* the B matrix */
    double *cc1;    /* A x B computed */
    double *buffer; /* Row to send to slave for processing */
    double *ans;    /* Computed answer for master */
    int myid, numprocs;
    int i, j, numsent, sender;
    int row, anstype;
    double starttime, endtime;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
    if (argc > 1) {
        nrows = atoi(argv[1]);
        ncols = nrows;
        if (myid == 0) {
            /* Master Code */
            aa = gen_matrix(nrows, ncols);
            bb = gen_matrix(ncols, nrows);
            cc1 = malloc(sizeof(double) * nrows * nrows);
            starttime = MPI_Wtime();
            buffer = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols);
            numsent = 0;
            MPI_Bcast(bb, ncols*nrows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD); /*broadcast bb to all slaves*/
            for (i = 0; i < min(numprocs-1, nrows); i++) {                  /*for each process or row*/
                for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {                               /*for each column*/
                    buffer[j] = aa[i * ncols + j];                          /*get row of aa*/
                }
                MPI_Send(buffer, ncols, MPI_DOUBLE, i+1, i+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD); /*send row to slave*/
                numsent++;                                                     /*increment number of rows sent*/
            }
            ans = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols);
            for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
                MPI_Recv(ans, ncols, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG,
                         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                sender = status.MPI_SOURCE;
                anstype = status.MPI_TAG;

                for (i = 0; i < ncols; i++){
                    cc1[(anstype-1) * ncols + i] = ans[i];
                }

                if (numsent < nrows) {
                    for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) {
                        buffer[j] = aa[numsent*ncols + j];
                    }
                    MPI_Send(buffer, ncols, MPI_DOUBLE, sender, numsent+1,
                             MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                    numsent++;
                } else {
                    MPI_Send(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, MPI_DOUBLE, sender, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            }

            endtime = MPI_Wtime();
            printf("%f\n",(endtime - starttime));
        } else {
            /* Slave Code */
            buffer = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols);
            bb = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols*nrows);
            MPI_Bcast(bb, ncols*nrows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_COMM_WORLD); /*get bb*/
            if (myid <= nrows) {
                while(1) {
                    MPI_Recv(buffer, ncols, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); /*recieve a row of aa*/
                    if (status.MPI_TAG == 0){
                        break;
                    }

                    row = status.MPI_TAG; /*get row number*/
                    ans = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols);
                    for (i = 0; i < ncols; i++){
                        ans[i]=0.0;
                    }
                    for (i=0; i<nrows; i++){
                        for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++) { /*for each column*/
                            ans[i] += buffer[j] * bb[j * ncols + i];
                        }
                    }
                    MPI_Send(ans, ncols, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, row, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                }
            }
        } /*end slave code*/
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage matrix_times_vector <size>\n");
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your final send you send only 0 reals, while waiting for ncols, this might cause problems. Better use MPI_Probe beforehand to figure out the size of the message. Better yet, figure out the partitioning beforehand so you know how many rows to receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message typically means that one at least of your MPI processes crashed and the whole MPI job subsequently aborted. It can be caused by any sort of error, but most of the time, it's a segmentation fault caused by an erroneous memory access.

I didn't look closely at the code, so I have no idea if the logic works etc, but what I can tell is that this line has an issue:

```
MPI_Recv(&ans, nrows, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

Indeed, there are two problems here:

1. `&ans` is a `**double`, which is not what you want, I guess you wanted `ans`
2. `ans` hasn't been allocated so it cannot be used as a receiving buffer

Try first to fix this and see what happens.

**EDIT**: on your new code you allocate `ans` like this:

```
ans = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * ncols);
```

then you initialise it like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    ans[i]=0.0;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
MPI_Send(ans, nrows, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, row, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

or

```
MPI_Recv(ans, nrows, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG,
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

This isn't coherent: is `ans`'s size `ncols` or `nrows`?

And what is your new error message?

Comment: &ans is actually a *double which represents my "matrix" in a 1-D array. I believe the allocation shouldn't be an issue as I pass the address, however I could be wrong. But, I allocated it anyway and I'm still recieving the same error.

Comment: You declared `double *ans; ` so `&ans` is a pointer to `ans`, and `ans` being a `double*` as declared, this therefore means that `&ans` is a pointer to `double*` aka a `double**`. And I repeat, you didn't allocate the memory for your receive buffer. Maybe you've done it now, and if so, just edit the question with your new code. And BTW, you also use `&ans` in the sending side, which is wrong as well. Finally, if you want to use `&` to make clearer that you used a pointer, then use `&ans[0]`

Comment: Right, not sure what I was thinking. It's been a little while since I've coded in C. I fixed that and edited the code above. I'm no longer getting the same error however it seems to be hung up on something still as it isn't exiting..

Comment: In my code ncols is always equal to nrows or the program will exit. But you're right, ideally it should be ncols (I edited my code to reflect this). There is no error this time, the code just wont exit. Also, my cc1 (the resulting matrix) only has  values (the correct ones) for the first 4 indices (the first row of a 4x4) and then the rest of them are still 0.

Comment: Wow... I just realized I was reusing 'i' inside a for loop that was already using i. Fixed that and my code works now. Thanks for the help!